# Numpy array, removing one arbitrary element per row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `N*K` dimensional numpy array `X` and want to construct `N*(K-1)` dimensional numpy array `Y` by removing the element 1 of the first row, element 3 of the second row, element 1 of the forth row .... element j on the Nth row.
The indices of th elements should be removed are stored in a N*1 dimensional vector `t`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a boolean selection mask:

```
mask = np.ones_like(X, dtype='bool')
mask[np.arange(X.shape[0]), idx] = 0
```

which would make defining `Y` and `t` easy:

```
import numpy as np
N, K = 3, 4
X = np.arange(N*K).reshape(N,K)
# idx indicates which element you wish to remove from each row
idx = np.arange(N)

mask = np.ones_like(X, dtype='bool')
mask[np.arange(X.shape[0]), idx] = 0

Y = X[mask].reshape(N, K-1)
t = X[~mask]
```

yields

```
In [17]: X
Out[17]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [15]: Y
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 11]])

In [16]: t
Out[16]: array([ 0,  5, 10])
```

Comment: an elegant answer. Thanks.